# Why does my computer restart?

Tags: ubuntu, reboot

How can a computer restart itself?

My computer system restarts many times in a day. It does this after certain intervals of time. I have checked the power plug, but its okay. My OS is Ubuntu 17.04

Comment: check the temperature of your PC, depending where you live it may be v.hot and your PC may be overheating.

Answer (score 1):

It's worth trying to see if the logs say anything about it: /var/log/boot

=> /var/log/messages : General log messages

=> /var/log/boot : System boot log

=> /var/log/debug : Debugging log messages

=> /var/log/auth.log : User login and authentication logs

=> /var/log/daemon.log : Running services such as squid, ntpd and others log message to this file

=> /var/log/dmesg : Linux kernel ring buffer log

=> /var/log/dpkg.log : All binary package log includes package installation and other information

=> /var/log/faillog : User failed login log file

=> /var/log/kern.log : Kernel log file

=> /var/log/lpr.log : Printer log file

=> /var/log/mail.* : All mail server message log files

=> /var/log/mysql.* : MySQL server log file

=> /var/log/user.log : All userlevel logs

=> /var/log/xorg.0.log : X.org log file

=> /var/log/apache2/* : Apache web server log files directory

=> /var/log/lighttpd/* : Lighttpd web server log files directory

=> /var/log/fsck/* : fsck command log

=> /var/log/apport.log : Application crash report / log file

Comment: ok i will this out

Answer (score 1):

Random restarting is frequently caused by a hardware malfunction related to the delivery of power to the computer.

- The computer's power supply may be inadequate for the computer's other hardware devices or malfunctioning.
- UPS (if a UPS is being used) may be inadequate or malfunctioning.
- An intermittent short in a power cable or power adapter. I have seen an intermittent short caused by a bug that was lodged inside an electric outlet. Another cause of an intermittent short is a wire that is either nearly broken at the point of connection or loosely connected.

In addition to all of the above, overheating can cause random restarting. In Ubuntu I use an application called [Psensor](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15832/how-do-i-get-the-cpu-temperature/628117#628117) to show information about computer temperatures by clicking on a little thermometer icon that is located in the notification area of the panel to the left of the clock.

Comment: I upgraded my RAM processor few days ago. UPS is not used and the electric outlet looks fine.